# mysql select all rows meeting the first and second lowest values?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by, limit

I wonder how I could select every user who met the first and second lowest values of a result table?

Table Test

```
NAME    VALUE
John    8
Marie   8
Luis    10
Carlos  10
Leo     13
Max     14
```

So the result in this case would be

```
NAME    VALUE
John    8
Marie   8
Luis    10
Carlos  10
```

Thanks a lot!

BTW, I did my home work searching on google and everything, didn't come up with anything but querying the table and then using PHP to filter that for me, not good for performance.

@Aziz I get the error : #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Thanks

Thank you all for the load of useful answers!

Just in case falls into funny results like I did, I needed more filters and had to add to the query, here follows:

SELECT * FROM `results_temp` WHERE
 semana='semana6' AND
 `total_pontos` IN (
   SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT `total_pontos` 
      FROM `results_temp`

```
   WHERE semana='semana6'

  ORDER BY `total_pontos` 
  LIMIT 0,2
```

) AS t
)

Regards

Comment: @LeandroCintrao- Welcome to stack Overflow... Now from next time make sure that before putting your question here do some home work i mean search it on google... Find related answers.. try that answer and then also if you dont find anything then put your question here with whatever you have done for that question i mean `Code` , `queriy' etc...

Comment: BTW, I did my home work searching on google and everything, didn't come up with anything but querying the table and then using PHP to filter that for me, not good for performance.

Comment: Then You should have to put that query and code here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE `value` IN (
   SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT `value` 
      FROM Test 
      ORDER BY `value` 
      LIMIT 0,2
   ) AS t
)
```

Comment: I get the error : #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Thanks

Comment: @LeandroCintrao Based on your comment, I have updated my answer above. Please try the modified query.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM Test t
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT t.value FROM Test t ORDER BY t.value LIMIT 2
           ) A ON t.value = A.value;
```

Check this [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9aafb/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
|   NAME | VALUE |
|--------|-------|
|   John |     8 |
|  Marie |     8 |
|   Luis |    10 |
| Carlos |    10 |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE
  value <= (SELECT MIN(Value)
            FROM tablename
            WHERE value>(SELECT MIN(VALUE)
                         FROM tablename))
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d8ca/1).

Answer (score 1):

The uncorrelated version of a given query is nearly always faster...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM tablename x 
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT value FROM tablename ORDER BY value LIMIT 2) y 
    ON y.value = x.value;
```